# Workbox: No way to re-validate pre-cached items?

Tags: offline-caching, workbox

I am using Workbox to make a CMS site offline-capable. I have the service worker insalling and pre-caching site pages, assets, and offline page. The problem is, with pre-caching, there appears to be no way to update the cache without modifying the service worker. In my case, it's a CMS, so authors will not be re-building this service worker when updating site content. I assumed I could just use the StaleWhileRevalidate strategy but to my dismay, there is no way to provide a caching strategy to "precacheAndRoute()" or "precache()" and "addRoute()". This seems to be an oversight by the Workbox team, but just to be sure, I'd like any feedback on how one might implement this solution without changing the service worker any time a site page is updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Will post here in case anyone finds themselves in a similar case.

According to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#serving_precached_responses, the following information tipped me off to the solution:

> The order in which you call precacheAndRoute() or addRoute() is important. You would normally want to call it early on in your service worker file, before registering any additional routes with registerRoute(). If you did call registerRoute() first, and that route matched an incoming request, whatever strategy you defined in that additional route will be used to respond, instead of the cache-first strategy used by workbox-precaching.

So I dumped "precacheAndRoute()" in favor of just "precache()". Then I did a registerRoute() with the StaleWhileRevalidate strategy matching those assets. The important part was specifying the cacheName as the precache:

```
new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: workbox.core.cacheNames.precache
})
```

Pretty simple in hindsight, but the documentation wasn't clear at first on what seemed like something that should be built right into preCacheAndRoute.